# Unable to use jupyter notebook in VScode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

When I run jupyter notebook in VScode, it will show the error message. Could someone tell me how to install the ipykernel. Thank you so much!

The fist line said "Python 2.7.16 64-bit needs install ipykernel."
when I click the install which in the blue icon, it will show that ipykernel can not be installed.

And vscode can not connet to the kernel: Python 2.7.16 64-bit
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCTVU.png)

Answer (score 1):

Please manually install this kernel "ipykernel" in the VS Code terminal: (`pip install ipykernel`)

If you have more than one python environment, please make sure that the VS Code terminal you are currently using is the environment you need ("Python 2.7.16 64-bit"). (Check python: `python --version` or `pip --version`)

[image]

If it still cannot install "ipykernel", please try to use another [python environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments) or reinstall [python](https://www.python.org/).

Reference: [Working with Jupyter Notebooks in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support).

Answer (score 0):

You may need to install the 'ipykernel' in your environment and activated it through "python -m ipykernel install --user". This will activate the kernel in this environment.